# How to restore Atlassian Source Tree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I am using Atlassian source tree to upload the updated code within the group, By mistake, I deleted the .git folder from my local system project directory.And now I can only see MyProjectName  c://Users/documents/MyProjectName on Atlassiiansource tree,  nothing else(branches or masters file) on the source tree. Could anyone please tell how to restore Atlassian source tree in its last position.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
PPP

Comment: You are using sourcetree connected to github?...then you can clone the repo again, like this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/clone-a-repository-into-sourcetree-780870050.html

Comment: Thanks Hackerman, it worked well.

Comment: I am glad to help :)